# How can I use VIM with remote files?

Tags: vim, cloud

I've tried googling but all I find are terrible tutorials that end up not being compatible with VIM that are out dated or require me to manually upload every single time instead of letting me work on a cloud..

I use Digital Ocean to do all my development and I normally use http://c9.io to do my development when I'm on the go, but when I'm home nothing beats VIM (especially because I've used it for years and it's incredibly effective when you learn all the shortcuts).

Anyways I guess my main question is, how can I use VIM to develop consistently on the cloud. Thanks.

Comment: Does C9 offer anything like Dropbox's directory syncing? If so, could you just use Vim to edit files in the synced directory?

Comment: Why not SSH into your Digital Ocean instance and run vim from there?

Comment: For that matter, if it supports scp, just use the netrw plugin: `:help pi_netrw`

Comment: It's simple: run Vim directly on your server.